# Iframes cannot be the solution is it?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am loading content into a twitter bootstrap modal and the issue I am having is that the content is rather long, that is requiring a sidebar. This content is a simple html page. Instead of using the modals sidebar it uses the iframe, and every where I look this is the only way to get external content into twitter boostraps modal.

```
<p><a data-toggle="modal" class="updateNotes" href="http://adambalan.com/aisis/aisis_update/UpdateNotes/index.html" data-target="#modal">READ MORE ABOUT IT!</a></p>

    <div class="modal hide fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Latest Updates!</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
     </div>   
    </div>
```

**The jquery:**

```
$('a.btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $(".modal-body").html('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" allowtransparency="true" src="'+url+'"></iframe>');
});
```

I need to NOT use a an iframe and to use the modals sidebar for the content that scrolls. any idea?

I have also tried to turn off scrolling in the iframe, but then the content doesn't scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Tried jQuery's load function?

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Probably not working when the content comes from another domain.

Comment: could you provide a js fiddle of how to implement this? I have read through the doc but I am not sure this will work.